# Python: Writing csv file in a loop (iterative way)

Tags: python, csv

I want to load  photos from a folder, detect  landmarks for them then running an equation for each photo based on the landmarks and storing the output value in a new column.

1. Load 1st photo
2. Run landmark detector
3. Run an equation based on the landmark values
4. Store the equation output in 1st column

Repeat all the above steps for the second photo but with storing the output in the second column and so on. 
My main issue is writing the values in the csv file in an iterative way (New column each time a photo is processed). 
Code:

```py
col_dir = 'test/*.jpg'

def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
        dets = detector(img)

        for  rect in (dets):

            shape = predictor(img, rect)
            shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
            equation = shape[0]+shape[1]

            with open('hb.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file,delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
                writer.writerow(equation)
```

**ERROR: 
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not numpy.float64**

Comment: If you want to write all the data to a single row, with each value in the next column, you shouldn't write a row for each element; the error is the result of `equation` not being an iterable, but a single `numpy.float64` value. You could instead add the values to a list and once you're done, write the list as a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I would simply go without involving a csv writer:

```
with open('hb.csv', 'a+', newline='') as file:
    file.write(f'{equation}\t')
```

This would write the value of your equation variable and put a tab in the end since you obviously want a tab-delimited csv.

EDIT: And also in `open` you'd want to use 'a+' for append existing file.

Comment: It combined all the values into one column with a "tab space" between them. I manged to do it following @tripleee comment. Thanks!